# Windows 10: do not allow pinning Store app to the Taskbar

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1903

I've tried to remove Store app from Taskbar on Windows 10 1903 Build 18362.1016 (using different ways like Group Policy, Registry and windows configuration) but it still appears each time after reboot.
Do you have any other ideas how to remove it permanently?

Comment: I am going to guess running `Windows 10 LTSB Enterprise` isn't an option?

Comment: Make a new, test, Windows User Account (Start, Settings, Accounts).  Log into the new Account and see if Store is on the Taskbar in the new Account. If not (likely), then it would appear the original user Profile has suffered some damage and needs to be replaced.

Comment: @Ramhound Hi! Yes, it is on my office laptop